# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS: Extremely slow writing speeds while writing to USB flash drives

Tags: usb, flash

Using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and Wi-Fi  I have been plagued with extremely slow speeds while writing to USB flash drives. Writing speeds have ranged from 5 to 50 kb/sec using flash drives that advertise up to 300 mb/sec.  I have searched in vain for a solution and I'm asking for help. - I will note, however, that during 2 out of 30 recent computer sessions- and for reasons unknown- I experienced some very fast file transfer speeds.  In view of this it certain that my computer and router are capable of handling fast transfer speeds- I just don't know how to make that happen.

---

The computer I’m using is a Dell XPS 13 9360.  A plate on the computer says “Reg Model P54G” on the right side.  On the left side it looks like it says “MSIP RMM E2K P54G002”. The plate also says “Mfg year 2017”.
    I didn’t see any colors (other than black) inside the USB ports.  Relevant descriptive info I located says “Ports:  **USB 3.1**, 3.5mm jack, SD Card, USB-C Thunderbolt 3.1t”.

About motherboard info:  With limited knowledge of proper command line syntax I have tried to use the suggested commands to obtain appropriate motherboard info. Responses I have received have included the following:

```
  Description: Motherboard
  product: 05JK94    
  vendor: Dell Inc. 
  physical ID: 0   
  version: A00
```

---

I have been using highly-rated Sandisk and Samsung flash drives (e.g., a Samsung Bar Plus 256 USB 3.1 flash drive that claims "speeds up to 300 mb/sec").
   * Any suggestions and/or solutions will be very much appreciated. *

Comment: Flash drive write speeds depend extremely on the kind of files you're writing. Writing many small files is usually significantly slower. You can get a good idea over the possible variations on this site - not all products hold what they promise, even from the same manufacturer: https://usb.userbenchmark.com/

Comment: The limiting factor probably is not the USB flash drives themselves, but the USB interface. Please advise 1) the color in the USB sockets on the PC [tells us if USB/USB2, USB3, USB 3.1] 2) the make & model of your PC; please get the model# off the serial# sticker, for other numbers elsewhere can be from Marketing & don't tell us what's inside. 3) Lastly, the model of your motherboard; please get the latter by running `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" && sudo lshw | grep -A5 "Moth" && lshw | grep product | head -n1` . Add the results of 1-3 in the question w/ [edit], not w/ Add Comment.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing valuable information and your suggestions for improving my question.  I have edited my question and have entered additional information (as suggested) about the USB ports, make and model, and motherboard.  Please let me know if there is any more helpful info I can provide.  — The extremely slow download speeds are a MAJOR problem for me and are greatly limiting the usefulness of my computer.  I appreciate- and will continue to appreciate- any suggestions or ideas relevant to solving this problem that can be provided by you and/or other community members.